# How to do onclick in CSS to do transition on image?

Tags: css, rotation, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to rotate image by 180 degrees. The code below is working on hover, how can I do this when the image is clicked?

Is there a simple way to do this by using **CSS**?

**CSS**

```
img {
    display: block;
}

.rotate {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.rotate:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <img class="rotate" src="/images/object.png" />
</body>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/a1r1hyyt/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can use the `:focus` on your rotate class which will make your image rotate on click, but be careful, clicking outside will lead to loosing the effect.

Below The Snippet.

```css
img {
    display: block;
margin: 20px;
}

.rotate {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    outline: 0;
}

.rotate:focus {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img class="rotate" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" tabindex="1" />
</body>
```

Comment: Nice but fragile. Effect can be triggered with a few TAB key presses. The only "real" answer here is that it's impossible.

Comment: Well @Amit I totally agree and i love collective learning that's why i will up-vote your answer and I suggest that your answer should be marked as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. click is not a state and there's no pseudo class defined for it, hover ***is***.

There are some tricks that can be used to simulate reacting to mouse clicks using plain CSS (such as using a checkbox), but the effects you can create this way are limited.

> EDIT: Since apparently I couldn't explain myself in the comments, here's Pyere example done with a checkbox instead. It works a little different, maybe better maybe worse (depending on the exact effect required) and in any case "limited" compared to a JS click handler

```css
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
}

.rotate {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    outline: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked+label>img {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="chkimage" id="chkimage"/><label for="chkimage"><img class="rotate" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></label>
```

Comment: @Legionar - what do you mean?

Comment: You can't "really" do it, because (as I answered) click is not a state and there's no pseudo class for it. You *CAN* simulate it in various ways (which is also part of my answer), but you'll always be limited in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to listen the click event :

```js
var rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');
rotate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rotate.classList.add('rotated');
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
.rotate {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="rotate" id="rotate" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There'r no solution with pure CSS. You can do it just with jQuery, with method .click().

```js
$( ".rotate" ).click(function() {
    //alert($( this ).css( "transform" ));
    if (  $( this ).css( "transform" ) == 'none' ){
        $(this).css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
    } else {
        $(this).css("transform","" );
    }
});
```

```css
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px;
}

img {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='rotate' src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="Google" />
```

Comment: Everything is possible, if you believe... I know it in jQuery, my question is in CSS.